# How to organize functions into script files to allow call from command line?

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-4.0

I have an Advanced Function with a number of helper functions in a .ps1 script file.

How do organize my functions so I can call AdvFunc from the command line and **not break the ability of AdvFunc to use the helper functions?**

Abbreviated contents of script.ps1:

```
Function AdvFunc {
    [cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Scheduled')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ParameterSetName='Scheduled')]$SomeValue
    )
    Begin {
        $value = Helper1 $stuff
    }
    Process {
        # do stuff
    }
    End {
        # call Helper2
    }
}

Helper1 {
    Param ($stuff)
    # do stuff
    Return $valueForAdvFunc
}

Helper2 {
    # do other stuff
}

# Entry Point
$collection | AdvFunc
```

script.ps1 is currently launched by a scheduler and processes pre-defined $collection as expected.

The problem is I need to call AdvFunc from the command like with a different parameter set. I've add the `AdHoc` Parameter Set below. This will be used to send a different collection to AdvFunc. As I understand things, this means the first lines of script.ps1 will now need to be:

```
Param (
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ParameterSetName='Scheduled')]$SomeValue,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AdHoc')][string]$OtherValue1,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AdHoc')][string]$OtherValue2
)
```

Obviously this means the helper functions can no longer be in the same .ps1 file.

Does this mean I will now need **3 script files**, each dot-sourcing the other as needed?

Should I use: **script.ps1** (containing only AdvFunc), **helpers.ps1** (containing the several helper functions), and **collection.ps1** (with only $collection being piped to script.ps1) ?

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by "want to call AdvFunc with an AdHoc  parameter set"? Do you want to redefine the parameter set(s) on the fly? Why? What do you think you need this for, i.e. what is the actual problem you want to solve by doing this?

Comment: The `AdHoc` Parameter Set is shown in the second code block.  It's not redefined. It's a new parameter set I need to add to AdvFunc. This additional parameter set will process an ad hoc task instead of the scheduled task that uses the built-in `$collection` with the `Scheduled` Parameter Set.

Answer (score 1):

Proposed solution: Use a launcher script that sources script.ps1.  All functions (AdvFunc and all helper functions) reside in script.ps1.

```
# launcher.ps1
[cmdletbinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Scheduled')]
Param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AdHoc', Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param1,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AdHoc', Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param2,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='AdHoc', Mandatory=$true)][ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][string]$Param3
)
. .\script.ps1
if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('param1')) {
    AdvFunc -Param1 $Param1 -Param2 $Param2 -Param3 $Param3
}
else {
    $collection | AdvFunc
}
```

The idea is to accommodate either no parameter (sending `$collection` to AdvFunc) or a full 'AdHoc' set of parameters (sending the command-line defined collection to AdvFunc).  The empty 'Scheduled' Parameter Set may not be necessary to accommodate the no parameter option.